# Change standalone Jenkins default URL

Tags: nginx, jenkins

Running Jenkins standalone (The WAR file, `java -war ./jenkins.war` or whatever the command is) listening on a non-standard port. I want to get NGINX to proxy from our HTTPS site /jenkins/ to this standalone.

```
location /jenkins/ {
    proxy_pass http://axolotl.ecogeek.local:10112/;
}
```

Problem is, Jenkins still things it's at the root URL so all requests are relative to that, so when accessing `/jenkins/` it redirects to `/login` but it needs to go to `/jenkins/login`, is there any way, through Jenkins or through NGINX, to change the root URL and get it to play nice?

### edit

Connecting to Jenkins on it's normal port I can go to Manage Jenkins->Configure System->Jenkins URL and change that, that fixes the redirection but all the media is being requested from /static/ (Have tried restarting Jenkins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go into the Jenkins control panel, you will see a "Manage Jenkins" link.  Somewhere down that page, you'll see "Jenkins URL".  Try setting that to example.com/jenkins or whatever scheme you have.

Take a look at:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Hudson+behind+Nginx

So, Jenkins is apparently stupid about some things, and you'll need rewrites.

Comment: Thanks, just found that (see edit) but the static stuff is still coming from /static/ =(

Comment: @sam See update

Answer (score 0):

Try making a 301 redirect from `/` to `/jenkins/` (be sure to carry the request data over).

Comment: There is other stuff at / I can't remove

Comment: Your solution will fail if the OP wants to have other stuff in /

Comment: Yes, true. Jenkins is a pain to get working through proxies, because it is written in a way that takes files relatively TO THE DOMAIN but not to the directory.